# Добавление данных JSON в ComboBox

Tags: java, json, javafx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего добавить данные из JSON в ComboBox.
Графическая часть сделана с помощью Scene Builder, есть класс Controls, где прописаны все id.
Привожу пример парсера

```
public class Parser {

private String filePath = "/Users/oleg/Documents/workspace/app/src/basebase.json";
public List<JSONObject> ParseJson() {

    List<JSONObject> resultList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    try {
        // read the json file
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);


        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

        JSONObject first = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Sample");

        resultList.add(first);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultList;
```

Так же демонстрирую структуру JSON

```
{
“Sample”: {
    “Text1”: 001,
    “Text2”: 002
  },
“Sample2”: {
    “Text1”: 001,
    “Text2”: 002
  }
}
```

Comment: что именно должно попасть в combobox и в каком формате?

Comment: В combobox должны попасть Sample, Sample2 и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, что в JSON у вас строки

```
  // json - переменная в которой содержится JSON в виде строки
  String json = ...;
  // decodeJSON - метод который вы напишите, что бы получить список с строк из JSON
  List<String> newItems = decodeJSON(json);
  ObservableList<String> items = combobox.getItems();
  items.addAll(newItems);
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ.
Насколько я понял, в методе decodeJSON должен происходить парсинг?

Comment: Да. Там надо разобрать json.

Comment: Тогда, чем здесь (decodeJSON(json)) является json в скобках?

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: покажите структуру вашего JSON в вопросе

Comment: Добавил структуру JSON